# Create toggle with CSS and HTML with input variable Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

I have created an Angular component that displays a toggle-switch. The functionalities of the switch are what I want, i.e. it switches correctly when I click on it. The only extra thing I want to add, is that the initial state is based on a boolean Input variable *enableSwitch*.

So when I display the toggle switch like this:

```
<toggle-switch [enableSwitch]="true"></toggle-switch>
```

I want initially the toggle being enabled (rectangle on the right). When I click on it, I want to toggle to the disabled state, and I want to return the boolean as *false*.

The same function applies when I want to display the toggle initially being disabled:

```
<toggle-switch [enableSwitch]="false"></toggle-switch>
```

I have created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MGcs6CMl6fZEeVLPu1eP) to demonstrate the problem.

Can anyone help me further?

Comment: To toggle the boolean, I forgot (click)="toggleSwitch()" in the span with class="slider" in toggle-switch.component.html.

Comment: the @Input() binding - is used for sharing data between components, so when the Parent wants to inform the child something has changed - it will receive that. You also need to bind the property to the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a two-way binding approach, using ngModel.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="enableSwitch">
```

To instanciate the variable as true, you could do:

```
@Input() enableSwitch: boolean = true;
```

The click event would then be obsolete.

Rememeber to include the **FormsModule** in app.ts.

See forked example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/TIxr6BGrXeVmPYO35DrQ?p=preview

---

**EDIT:**

In case of two-way databinding on the component - https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

You first need the banana-in-a-box syntax:

```
<toggle-switch [(enableSwitch)]="enable"></toggle-switch>
```

Then you need to use an EventEmitter with the special variable name **fooChange** where **foo** is the @Input name.

```
@Output() enableSwitchChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
@Input() enableSwitch: Boolean = true;
```

Then emit the updated value when the value changes:

```
update() {
    this.enableSwitchChange.emit(this.enableSwitch);
}
```

To call the update() function you can use change.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="enableSwitch" (change)="update()">
```

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lx7QDbKt6V3HdFJN3bZx?p=preview

This can also be solved simpler without ngModel, but you probably see how yourself. =)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe it wasn't clear from my question that I want the initial variable to rely on what is passed through. You set enableSwitch to true at @Input, but I want to give the boolean (which will be a variable later on) in the html call to toggle-switch. Is that possible with your solution?

Comment: Yes, when you use the @Input it will get the value from the attribute. My solution will set the value to true in case it is not supplied.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I created a fork of your solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/H8NRlhfw3aKBsLMDGElM. Now in app.ts I give a variable enable to initialize the toggle. I alse display the variable two times, but the second one always stays as initially given through. Is there a possibility to alse give back the current value and save that as the enable-variable?

Comment: Aha, I see. What you want is a two-way databinding on the compoentent. Here is a fork doing this: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lx7QDbKt6V3HdFJN3bZx?p=preview . This is well documented here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

Comment: Thanks for your solution!